# Confusion over API endpoints in React project

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, express

I'm building a full-stack MERN app, where users can submit reviews.

I'm confused about how routing and API endpoints work, and here's my problem: I'm trying to view my  `AddReview`  component in the browser, but instead I'm getting a  `cannot /GET` error message.
What's adding to my confusion is that I can however view the `AllReviews` component at `localHost:3000/`.
So could someone please explain how routing and accessing API resources works in relation to this project, because my understanding of this is all a bit hazy.

Anyway - here's how I've configured my routes:

`App.jsx`

```
import React from 'react'
import {BrowserRouter as Router, Switch, Route} from 'react-router-dom'
import AllReviews from './AllReviews'
import AddReview from './AddReview'

const App = () => {

  return (
    <>
    <Router>
    <div>
      <Switch>
      <Route path ='/' component = {AllReviews}/>
      <Route path = '/add-review'  component = {AddReview}/>
      </Switch>
    </div>
    </Router>
    </>
  )
}

export default App
```

Here's the component I'm trying to render in the browser (but can't)

```
AddReview.jsx
```

```
import React from 'react'

const AddReview = () => {
    return(
        <div>
            <form>
                <label>
                    User name
                    <input type = 'text' id = 'userName' name = 'userName'></input>
                </label>
                <label>
                    Rating
                    <input type = 'number' id = 'stars' name = 'stars'></input>
                </label>
                <label>
                    Title
                    <input type = 'text' id = 'title' name = 'title'></input>
                </label>
                <label>
                    Photo
                    <input type = 'text' id = 'photo' name = 'photo'></input>
                </label>
                <label>
                   Blurb
                    <input type = 'text' id = 'blurb' name = 'blurb'></input>
                </label>
                <button type = 'submit'>Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    )
}

export default AddReview
```

And here's the express routes:

```
const path = require('path')
const express = require('express')
const cors = require('cors')
const mongoose = require('mongoose')
const Review = require('./models/reviews')


const server = express()

// server.use(express.json())
server.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, './public')))
server.use(cors())


//Mongoose config
const dbURI = ***
mongoose.connect(dbURI, {useNewUrlParser:true, useUnifiedTopology:true})
.then(() => {
    console.log('connected to db')
})
.catch((err) => {
    console.log(err)
})

//Routes

//GET all reviews
server.get('/all-reviews', (req,res) => {
    Review.find()
    .then((result) => {
        res.send(result)
    })
    .catch(err => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})

// POST a review
server.post('/new-review', (req,res) => {
    const review = new Review(req.body)
    review.save()
    .then(()=>{
        console.log('review successfully posted')
    })
})

//Add a new review
server.get('/add-review', (req,res) => {
    const review = new Review({
        userName: 'Josh',
        stars:5,
        title: 'Review of Customs Coffee',
        photo: 'https://images.immediate.co.uk/production/volatile/sites/30/2020/08/hub-image-coffee-e732616.jpg?quality=90&resize=504,458',
        blurb: 'yes this was some very nice coffee'
    })
   review.save()
    .then((result) => {
        res.send(result)
    })
    .catch((err) => {
        console.log(err)
    })
})


module.exports = server
```

Comment: Now you need to rotate the MongoDB credentials you've publicly shared. In terms of the question it seems like you're expecting both a client page and a server endpoint at /add-review, and also that you don't have and kind of fallback for "push state" client-side routing.

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/258066/how-to-handle-a-publicly-posted-api-key-or-password-or-other-sensitive-informa

Answer (score 0):

React Router picks the first `Route` matching the current path, so here `/add-reviews` matches the first `Route` path (wich is `/`). I'd suggest to add the `exact` props to the first `Route`, so `/add-reviews` won't match it anymore.

See https://reactrouter.com/web/api/Route